# Should we use semicolon at the end of variable names in python?

Tags: python-2.7, variables, syntax

In the code below, should we use semicolon at the end of assignment to `num` or not? Why?

```
# Python code to check whether a number 
# is even or odd using bool()


def check(num):
    return(bool(num%2==0))

# Driver Code
num = 8;
if(check(num)):
    print("Even")
else:
    print("Odd")
```

Answer (score 3):

Many programming languages like C, C++, Java and others use semicolons to separate statements. In Python the semicolons are optional for single statements in a line. They are only mandatory, if you want write multiple statements in the same line. Some Python programmers write semicolons at the end of the line, because they are so used to it from other languages.

Thus, there is no need for the semicolon after `num = 8`, and you should avoid it, because it's unusual.

Answer (score 1):

Semicolon is not required in your variable(s), but if you put them in one line, it will be more readable. Consider this `x=2 y=3` and `x=2; y=3`

Comment: A semicolon is mandatory to separate multiple statements in a single line. Your example `x=2 y=3` gives a syntax error.

Comment: x = 2 y=3
      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Perhaps you meant `x, y  = 2, 3`. where there is a `y` between `x` and it's value.  Likewise, `y` has the `2` between it and the `3`.   Tuple unpacking is common in Python.  However, tastes vary,